# Looking For Joomla Plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla

This isn't a development question, I'm Looking for a plugin for Joomla that allows users to login to a secure zone with universal credentials that will be provided by admin. After logging in that user will be granted access and will be able to download private files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a component, not a plugin. The word 'plugin' has special meaning in Joomla. See here for an explanation:
http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29

I would suggest looking at something like DocMan:
http://www.joomlatools.eu/products/docman